# Terraform variables not allowed

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a simple use case where I am provisioning a key vault but want to define a variable as its only really needed here (local) but I get the `error variable not allowed`.

```
variable "secrets" {
    type = map(string)
    default = {
      "price-cosmos-db-primary-key" = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.acc.primary_key
      "price-cosmos-db-endpoint" = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.acc.endpoint  
    }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "keyvaultsecrets" {
  count = length(local.secrets)
  name = keys(local.secrets)[count.index]
  value = values(local.secrets)[count.index]
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.price_keyvault.id
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_cosmosdb_account.acc
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to do the equivalent but using `locals`?

Comment: You cannot assign values to variables in such a way, i.e., by referencing the arguments/attributes from resources. You probably want outputs.

Comment: The only way I was able to do this was to use a separate variable file but that didn't make sense as it's only scoped to this file. Looking for an elegant solution..

Comment: Ok, so you cannot do this: `"price-cosmos-db-primary-key = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.acc.primary_key`. Where is the resource coming from? A module? The same root module?

Comment: Also, the way you have defined it is not a local variable, rather a regular one, so you cannot use `local.secrets` references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use locals, it will work.

```
locals {
  secrets = {
      "price-cosmos-db-primary-key" = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.acc.primary_key
      "price-cosmos-db-endpoint" = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.acc.endpoint  
    }
}
```

Comment: This saved me lots of stress and searching, thank you.